# Python Setup.py: set environment variable prior to running install_requires

Tags: python, pip, environment-variables, airflow, setup.py

Recently, a change to Apache Airflow requires setting an environment variable SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes before it is able to be installed:
https://airflow.apache.org/installation.html

In my custom module's setup.py script, I'm including Airflow in the `install_requires` list. So, when I try to install my custom module, it also fails looking for that environment variable to be set.

Since I have a lot of environments to install this into, I want to set that environment variable automatically in my setup.py module so it is always present. However, It doesn't seem to work if I simply put this line at the top of my setup.py or inside of the run() method of a custom subclass of install (via the cmdclass setup.py option).

```
os.environ['SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE'] = 'yes'
```

Any thoughts on how I can set an environment variable in a setup.py before any of the `install_requires` dependencies are installed?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It should work out-of-the-box if you run `export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes` before `pip install YOUR_CUSTOM_PACKAGE`.

An alternative option is to use the following in your `setup.py`:

```
import os
os.system("export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes")
```

Comment: Thanks kaxil. Interesting idea to make use os.system instead of os.environ. I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1):

How is your custom module installed? Using wheels? Then you're out of luck as `setuptools` run `setup.py` at compile/package time but not at the installation time. With wheels the only solution is to set the environment variable before installation:

```
SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes pip install …
```

You trick with `setup.py` should work if you install from sdist (source distribution).

Comment: Thank you phd. I'm using sdists at the moment (but might be nice to use a wheel eventually).  Ya, I was hoping to avoid setting the env variable before pip install since I have a dozen or so places to include that.